# jQuery Script fails after outsourcing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built a small script that redirects users based on a selected label.

**ON-PAGE SCRIPT**

```
<form id="contact" method="POST" name="contact">
  <label for="request" class="mandatory">
    <select id="request" required>
        <option selected="selected" value="">-Please select-</option>
        <option value="A">Selection A</option>
        <option value="B">Selection B</option>
      </select>
    </label>
</form>
<input id="redirect" type="hidden" name="redirect" value=""/>
<input class="send" onclick="submit_form();" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Mail" />
</form>
<script>
$("form").ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="A"){
                  $("#redirect").val("http://example.com/a");
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="B"){
                    $("#redirect").val("http://example.com/b");
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
```

On-page the script works fine but now I'm struggling with outsourcing it into an external JS file.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact_form" method="POST" name="contact_form">
  <label for="request" class="mandatory">
    <select id="request" required>
        <option selected="selected" value="">-Please select-</option>
        <option value="A">Selection A</option>
        <option value="B">Selection B</option>
      </select>
    </label>
</form>
<input id="redirect" type="hidden" name="redirect" value=""/>
<input class="send" onclick="submit_form();" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Mail" />
<script src="/form/flexRequest.js"></script>
<script>
$("form").ready(function(){
  flexRequest();
});
</script>
```

**JS FILE**

```
function flexRequest(){
 $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="A"){
                  $("#redirect").val("http://example.com/a");
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="B"){
                    $("#redirect").val("http://example.com/b");
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
```

As you can see, I'm aware that I need to integrate the JS file and initialize it on a certain page event like `pagecreate`. But I'm struggling on a final solution.

Comment: form does not have a ready event.... It should be document.

Comment: So are you the script is being loaded correctly? Do you see if as a 404 in the network panel in your developer tools? What is the error in the console?

Comment: @epascarello Sorry not your script. I just copied it from my answer. Okay, if it makes no sense, then my answer is wrong. You are more experienced than me. I'll go with you until there's a [mcve] is created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can catch directly the .change event of your selectbox and avoid using the IF statements etc.

And just set the new value of your hidden input with id `#redirect` ...

```
<form id="contact_form" method="POST" name="contact_form">
  <label for="request" class="mandatory">
    <select id="request" required>
        <option selected="selected" value="">-Please select-</option>
        <option value="A">Selection A</option>
        <option value="B">Selection B</option>
      </select>
    </label>
</form>
<input id="redirect" type="hidden" name="redirect" value=""/>
<input class="send" onclick="submit_form();" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Mail" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#request").change(function(){
        var request_value = $(this).val();
        $("#redirect").val("http://example.com/"+request_value);
    });
});
</script>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d92u3yqt/)